# Certificate 'not verified' when doing 802.x1 authentication on Apple ios

Tags: certificate, ios, apple, 802.1

I've setup a new wifi network including a Freeradius server. Everything works fine except that Apple iOS gives a 'certificate not verified' warning when connecting. When the user accept the certificate, everything works fine.

I've verified the certificate chain and everything is ok. OSX and Ubuntu for example do the same check when connecting and they give me a green 'verified'-status.

How can I get a 'verified'-status on Apple iOS without supplying a .mobileconfig-file to every user.  (I don't manage every client)

[image: ios certificate warning]

Answer (score 2):

When I set up FreeRADIUS last year with an internal CA, and all BYOD devices, this was an issue on every desktop and mobile OS. I simply instructed the users to click Accept, and if they were truly paranoid, they could stop by and see me to manually verify the certificate. A few did.

If you don't control the devices and can't install your CA certificate on them, you don't really have any other good options.

Comment: The strange part for my situation is that Mac OSX (every version from 10.6 till 10.9) marks the certificate chain as valid and doesn't warn the user. It's only ios that gives such a warning.

Comment: Yes, it would be strange if Mac OS X doesn't warn the user.